# Почему не работает синтаксис PHP в PHPStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Ребят, привет. Не могу разобраться в проблеме PhpStorm. Сейчас приходится работать с кодом, в котором все вставлено в html. Сам файл имеет формат php.
Однако все что написано в `<??>` игнорируется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можно ли как-то это исправить?
P.S. Все что написано до начала html работает исправно. Заменить `<??>` на `<?php?>` - не помогает.

Еще есть такой момент, то (последние 2 изображения), если есть какая-то синтаксическая ошибка, то цвет подсвечивается нормально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте скачать плагин для php
[https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6610-php](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6610-php)